# Undo iptables terminal command

Tags: command-line, iptables

I executed the following script, and now need help to undo it.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Comment: do a reboot?!? that addition is only in memory not saved

Comment: I'm afraid of doing that and make everything worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

---

**One:**

You can list the rule by rule number and delete that by using the number.

The `PREROUTING` chain belong to the `nat` table; let's list all rules belonging to the table:

```
sudo iptables -t nat --line-numbers --numeric --list
```

Look at the rule number on the leftmost column; assuming the number is 2:

```
sudo iptables -t nat --delete PREROUTING 2
```

**Take extra care when picking the rule number, otherwise you might be removing the wrong rule.**

---

**Two:**

Another way would be to delete the rule by expression:

```
sudo iptables -t nat --delete PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 \
        -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
```

Note that, in this case the rule specification needs to match exactly.